# Generator Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning, coding-theory

I have a C in $F_2^6$

$(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \to (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_1+x_2,x_3+x_4)$

for $x = (1,0,1,1)$ i get $c = (1,0,1,1,1,0)$

we know that $$c = G . x$$

G is the Generator Matrix

in the solution G is
$$
G = \left[\frac{I_4}{A}\right] = \begin{bmatrix}    
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \hline
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

My problem is I want to get myself to the Matrix A in another word G! because i have only the solution without steps!

Comment: (1) I think you're missing a line in $G$.  There should be a line $0, 0, 1, 0$ inserted into the third line of the matrix. (2) I don't understand what you're asking.  Do you want to know how to generate codewords?  Or are you asking something else?

Comment: OK i got it

it's simpler as i though
we just get coefficients and place them in the matrix
$$
c = \left[\frac{I_4}{A}\right] = \begin{bmatrix}    
    x_1 \\
    x_2 \\
    x_3 \\
    x_4 \\
    \hline
    x_1 + x_2 \\
    x_3 + x_4
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: In essence this looks ok, though the notation is off.  A 'message word', $x$ maps to a code word: $$x \rightarrow Gx=\left[\begin{array}{c} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_1+x_2\\x_3+x_4 \end{array}\right]$$